# const Variables not updating without window reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to have my login page redirect to my main page.
I do this by using:

```
this.props.history.push("/userdashboard");
```

This works but on The main page there are const variables pulled in from `Constants.js`, which contains `USER_ID`, set from local storage:

```
let user_id = null;
try {
  user_id =
    window.localStorage.getItem("user_info") &&
    JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("user_info")).user_id;
} catch (err) {
  console.error("Error Parsing user_info user_id");
}
const USER_ID = user_id;

export { USER_ID };
```

and then imported with

```
import { USER_ID} from "../constants/Constants";
```

The problem is that, these constants are still null and do not contain the new information until the page is reloaded.

I would like to be able to do this without using `location.reload`, as I want the user to be pushed into a specific page sometimes.

This is coming from my login page which waits for the action to finish then pushes

```
this.props.loginFunc(login_data).then(() => this.completeLogin());

completeLogin() {
  this.props.history.push("/userdashboard");
}
```

I cannot figure out a way to refresh this `const` data. Also I am not entirely sure why these constants are used for getting the item from local storage every time, which is not expected, and is used in enough places that it would be a pain to refactor.

Comment: Constants cannot be changed during runtime

Comment: Is there a way to reload and relocate with the state in React?

Comment: Const. Not Updating. That is literally the point of a const.

Comment: I got that I just thought a new class or page was a new instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that `const` vs `let` (vs `var`, I guess) makes a difference, here. What is important that the localStorage is being read once. *When* is it supposed to be updated after the one initial reading? I don't see that piece of code.

Put this line

```
user_id = window.localStorage.getItem("user_info") && JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("user_info")).user_id;
```

where the script should check for updates, if you expect updates at runtime.

Comment: This is what I was trying to avoid doing but it seems to be the only thing I can do thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of constants is that they cannot be reassigned. So each time the `Constants.js` is imported, it will always use the previous const value.

You've already got a `let user_id` variable, simply export that

```
let user_id = null
try {
  user_id = window.localStorage.getItem("user_info") && JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("user_info")).user_id
}
catch(err) {
  console.error("Error Parsing user_info user_id")
}

export {
  USER_ID: user_id,
}
```

Comment: @DRuss no, modules aren't classes. If you need a class, you can use a class.